# Number of total stereoisomers of a piperazine derivative

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

[image: 3,6-dimethylpiperazine-2,5-dione]

How do I find out the **total number of stereoisomers** of 3,6-dimethylpiperazine-2,5-dione?

As far as I can see, the compound has two chiral carbons. Would the nitrogens make a difference? They seem chiral as well (three different groups and a lone pair).

My book says there are 3 total stereoisomers, but I expected more. It has considered only two chiral carbons, and nothing has been said about the nitrogens. Why?

Comment: Nitrogen's lone pair is conjugated with C=O and effectively doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh, right! Good observation!

Comment: Is that the only reason? How can you be so sure? Do you have a source?

Comment: Yes I think that's the only reason. I can be so sure because I've learned some chemistry in my life. Source? What source?

Comment: The _meso_ compound in this example is quite interesting looking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a sophomore organic chemistry text book question, so I won't elaborate possible stereoisomers involving lone pairs on nitrogen atoms. Nonetheless, 3,6-dimethylpiperazine-2,5-dione has 2 chiral carbon centers so that it should theoretically have $2^2 = 4$ stereoisomers. If you look at the molecule, it has center of symmetry (*i*):

[image]

Therefore, two of the isomers are identical and we call it *meso*-isomer. Thus, total isomers of this molecule are three: ($3R,6R$)-, ($3S,6S$)-, and  ($3R,6S$)- (($3S,6R$)- is essentially ($3R,6S$)-).